# Campo de formulário acima de todos os elementos na página

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site, porém ocorreu um pequeno bug do qual não consigo resolver, existe um formulário de busca na div principal, e um menu que fica fixo, acima de qualquer elemento na página. Porém, ao abrir o menu, o input do formulário fica acima do menu, como se tivesse um z-index maior que o do menu, o que causa, e como posso resolver este problema?

```js
 //MenuOpenClose
 function mainMenu(){
  var maskMenu = document.getElementById("mask-menu");
  var openMenuBtn = document.getElementById("main-menu-open");
  var closeMenuBtn = document.getElementById("main-menu-close");
  
  var openMenu = function(){
   document.documentElement.classList.add("menu-active");
   maskMenu.style.display = "block";   
   setTimeout(function(){
    maskMenu.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.6)";
   },50);
  }
  var closeMenu = function(){
   maskMenu.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
   document.documentElement.classList.remove("menu-active");
   setTimeout(function(){
    maskMenu.style.display = "none";
   },600);
  }

  maskMenu.style.display = "none";

  openMenuBtn.onclick = function(){openMenu()};
  closeMenuBtn.onclick = function(){closeMenu()};
  maskMenu.onclick = function(){closeMenu()};

 }
 mainMenu();
 //ScrollDetect
 function detectaRolagem(){
  var menuPrincipal = document.getElementById("menu-principal");
  if(document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 15){
   menuPrincipal.classList.add("offTop");
  }else{
   menuPrincipal.classList.remove("offTop");
  };

 }detectaRolagem();

 window.onscroll = function(){detectaRolagem()}
 document.onload = function(){detectaRolagem()}
 //PrincipalContent
 function conteudoPrincipal(){
  var principal = document.getElementById("principal");
  principal.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
 }conteudoPrincipal();

 window.onresize = function(){conteudoPrincipal()};
 document.onload = function(){conteudoPrincipal()}
```

```css
/* RESET.css */
*{
 color:inherit;
 font-family:inherit;
 background-color:inherit;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration:none;
 border:none;
 font-size:inherit;
 outline:none;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 list-style:none;
}
.sr-only {
 position:absolute;
 width:1px;
 height:1px;
 margin:-1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}
html,body{
 height:100%;
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
img{
 width:100%;
}

/* Navbar */
nav{
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
 border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
 transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
 padding:0 3.125%;
}
nav.offTop{
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
nav > div{
 padding:12px;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 position:relative;
 justify-content:space-between;
 width:100%; 
}
.social-icons{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:space-around;
}
.social-icons li{
 margin:0 4px;
 padding:4px;
}
#menu-links{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:-100%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 width:80%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 padding:16px;
 transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
 z-index:20;
}
#mask-menu{
 transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 z-index:10;
}
html.menu-active #menu-links{
 left:0;
}
.menu-buttons button:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
}
#menu-links .menu-buttons{
 align-self:flex-end;
}
#menu-links form fieldset{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 position:relative;
}
#menu-links form fieldset input{
 padding:6px 12px;
}
#menu-links form fieldset button{
 position:absolute;
 right:12px;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
}
#menu-links form fieldset button span{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}
#menu-links li{
 padding:6px 0;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:stretch;
}
.menu-outtop{
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#principal{
 padding:64px 3.125%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
#principal h2{
 font-size:1.3em;
 margin:0 0 12px;
 color:#111439;
}
#principal form fieldset{
 display:flex;
 position:relative;
 align-items:center;
}
#principal form input{
 border: 1px solid #a0a9b6;
 padding:6px 12px;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}
#principal form button{
 position:absolute;
}


#footer{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 padding:12px 3.125% 32px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav id="menu-principal">
  <span id="mask-menu"></span>
  <div>
   <ul class="social-icons">
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Facebook</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#194880" d="M5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3M18,5H15.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,0 12,8.5V11H10V14H12V21H15V14H18V11H15V9A1,1 0 0,1 16,8H18V5Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Twitter</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#009ec6" d="M5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3M17.71,9.33C18.19,8.93 18.75,8.45 19,7.92C18.59,8.13 18.1,8.26 17.56,8.33C18.06,7.97 18.47,7.5 18.68,6.86C18.16,7.14 17.63,7.38 16.97,7.5C15.42,5.63 11.71,7.15 12.37,9.95C9.76,9.79 8.17,8.61 6.85,7.16C6.1,8.38 6.75,10.23 7.64,10.74C7.18,10.71 6.83,10.57 6.5,10.41C6.54,11.95 7.39,12.69 8.58,13.09C8.22,13.16 7.82,13.18 7.44,13.12C7.81,14.19 8.58,14.86 9.9,15C9,15.76 7.34,16.29 6,16.08C7.15,16.81 8.46,17.39 10.28,17.31C14.69,17.11 17.64,13.95 17.71,9.33Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Instagram</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#285fa8" d="M7.8,2H16.2C19.4,2 22,4.6 22,7.8V16.2A5.8,5.8 0 0,1 16.2,22H7.8C4.6,22 2,19.4 2,16.2V7.8A5.8,5.8 0 0,1 7.8,2M7.6,4A3.6,3.6 0 0,0 4,7.6V16.4C4,18.39 5.61,20 7.6,20H16.4A3.6,3.6 0 0,0 20,16.4V7.6C20,5.61 18.39,4 16.4,4H7.6M17.25,5.5A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 18.5,6.75A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 17.25,8A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 16,6.75A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 17.25,5.5M12,7A5,5 0 0,1 17,12A5,5 0 0,1 12,17A5,5 0 0,1 7,12A5,5 0 0,1 12,7M12,9A3,3 0 0,0 9,12A3,3 0 0,0 12,15A3,3 0 0,0 15,12A3,3 0 0,0 12,9Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Youtube</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#e42c27" d="M10,16.5V7.5L16,12M20,4.4C19.4,4.2 15.7,4 12,4C8.3,4 4.6,4.19 4,4.38C2.44,4.9 2,8.4 2,12C2,15.59 2.44,19.1 4,19.61C4.6,19.81 8.3,20 12,20C15.7,20 19.4,19.81 20,19.61C21.56,19.1 22,15.59 22,12C22,8.4 21.56,4.91 20,4.4Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="menu-buttons">
    <button id="main-menu-open"><span class="sr-only">Abrir menu</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M3,6H21V8H3V6M3,11H21V13H3V11M3,16H21V18H3V16Z" /></svg></span></button>
   </div>
   <ul id="menu-links">
    <div class="menu-buttons">
     <button id="main-menu-close"><span class="sr-only">Fechar menu</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" /></svg></span></button>
    </div>
    <li class="search-bar">
     <form method="post" action="">
      <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="" placeholder="O que você procura?">
       <button type="submit"><span class="sr-only">Pesquisar</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5C16,11.11 15.41,12.59 14.44,13.73L14.71,14H15.5L20.5,19L19,20.5L14,15.5V14.71L13.73,14.44C12.59,15.41 11.11,16 9.5,16A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 3,9.5A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 9.5,3M9.5,5C7,5 5,7 5,9.5C5,12 7,14 9.5,14C12,14 14,12 14,9.5C14,7 12,5 9.5,5Z" /></svg></span></button>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Página inicial</a></li>
    <li><a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="contato.php">Contato</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div id="main-content">
  <div id="principal" class="search-form">
   <h2>Qual o seu problema?</h2>
   <form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ex: Assinatura de E-mail">
     <button type="submit"><span class="sr-only">Pesquisar</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5C16,11.11 15.41,12.59 14.44,13.73L14.71,14H15.5L20.5,19L19,20.5L14,15.5V14.71L13.73,14.44C12.59,15.41 11.11,16 9.5,16A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 3,9.5A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 9.5,3M9.5,5C7,5 5,7 5,9.5C5,12 7,14 9.5,14C12,14 14,12 14,9.5C14,7 12,5 9.5,5Z" /></svg></span></button>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   <p><a href="#" id="scroll-newest-videos">Talvez a solução esteja aqui!</a></p>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Se colocares um https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , terás mais chance de ser ajudado Murilo

Comment: eu mexi em todas as propriedades CSS, e o JS inteiro é para o Menu, por isso coloquei tudo

Comment: Murilo basta colocares no `nav#menu-principal` um `z-index:1`. Testa lá para ver

Comment: posta como resposta man, mas por que isso ocorre ?

Comment: Murilo não vou postar como porque não sei porque ocorre, nunca tive interesse suficiente por isso para aprofundar. Mas espero que alguém saiba e te consiga responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que algumas vezes estruturamos o `css` e não nos preocupamos com a hierarquia no `DOM`, elementos como o `inputs`, tendem a sobrepor tudo o que não estiver setado com z-index adequado e ou position absolute ou relative, ainda mais quando esses elementos estão acima deles, então uma solução simples para o seu caso foi transferir o menu lateral para o final do código...

```js
 //MenuOpenClose
 function mainMenu(){
  var maskMenu = document.getElementById("mask-menu");
  var openMenuBtn = document.getElementById("main-menu-open");
  var closeMenuBtn = document.getElementById("main-menu-close");
  
  var openMenu = function(){
   document.documentElement.classList.add("menu-active");
   maskMenu.style.display = "block";   
   setTimeout(function(){
    maskMenu.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.6)";
   },50);
  }
  var closeMenu = function(){
   maskMenu.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
   document.documentElement.classList.remove("menu-active");
   setTimeout(function(){
    maskMenu.style.display = "none";
   },600);
  }

  maskMenu.style.display = "none";

  openMenuBtn.onclick = function(){openMenu()};
  closeMenuBtn.onclick = function(){closeMenu()};
  maskMenu.onclick = function(){closeMenu()};

 }
 mainMenu();
 //ScrollDetect
 function detectaRolagem(){
  var menuPrincipal = document.getElementById("menu-principal");
  if(document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 15){
   menuPrincipal.classList.add("offTop");
  }else{
   menuPrincipal.classList.remove("offTop");
  };

 }detectaRolagem();

 window.onscroll = function(){detectaRolagem()}
 document.onload = function(){detectaRolagem()}
 //PrincipalContent
 function conteudoPrincipal(){
  var principal = document.getElementById("principal");
  principal.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
 }conteudoPrincipal();

 window.onresize = function(){conteudoPrincipal()};
 document.onload = function(){conteudoPrincipal()}
```

```css
/* RESET.css */
*{
 color:inherit;
 font-family:inherit;
 background-color:inherit;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration:none;
 border:none;
 font-size:inherit;
 outline:none;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 list-style:none;
}
.sr-only {
 position:absolute;
 width:1px;
 height:1px;
 margin:-1px;
 overflow:hidden;
 clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}
html,body{
 height:100%;
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
img{
 width:100%;
}

/* Navbar */
nav{
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
 border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
 transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
 padding:0 3.125%;
}
nav.offTop{
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
nav > div{
 padding:12px;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 position:relative;
 justify-content:space-between;
 width:100%; 
}
.social-icons{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:space-around;
}
.social-icons li{
 margin:0 4px;
 padding:4px;
}
#menu-links{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:-100%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 width:80%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
 padding:16px;
 transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
 z-index:20;
}
#mask-menu{
 transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 z-index:10;
}
html.menu-active #menu-links{
 left:0;
}
.menu-buttons button:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
}
#menu-links .menu-buttons{
 align-self:flex-end;
}
#menu-links form fieldset{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 position:relative;
}
#menu-links form fieldset input{
 padding:6px 12px;
}
#menu-links form fieldset button{
 position:absolute;
 right:12px;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
}
#menu-links form fieldset button span{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}
#menu-links li{
 padding:6px 0;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:stretch;
}
.menu-outtop{
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#principal{
 padding:64px 3.125%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
#principal h2{
 font-size:1.3em;
 margin:0 0 12px;
 color:#111439;
}
#principal form fieldset{
 display:flex;
 position:relative;
 align-items:center;
}
#principal form input{
 border: 1px solid #a0a9b6;
 padding:6px 12px;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}
#principal form button{
 position:absolute;
}


#footer{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 padding:12px 3.125% 32px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav id="menu-principal">
  <span id="mask-menu"></span>
  <div>
   <ul class="social-icons">
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Facebook</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#194880" d="M5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3M18,5H15.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,0 12,8.5V11H10V14H12V21H15V14H18V11H15V9A1,1 0 0,1 16,8H18V5Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Twitter</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#009ec6" d="M5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3M17.71,9.33C18.19,8.93 18.75,8.45 19,7.92C18.59,8.13 18.1,8.26 17.56,8.33C18.06,7.97 18.47,7.5 18.68,6.86C18.16,7.14 17.63,7.38 16.97,7.5C15.42,5.63 11.71,7.15 12.37,9.95C9.76,9.79 8.17,8.61 6.85,7.16C6.1,8.38 6.75,10.23 7.64,10.74C7.18,10.71 6.83,10.57 6.5,10.41C6.54,11.95 7.39,12.69 8.58,13.09C8.22,13.16 7.82,13.18 7.44,13.12C7.81,14.19 8.58,14.86 9.9,15C9,15.76 7.34,16.29 6,16.08C7.15,16.81 8.46,17.39 10.28,17.31C14.69,17.11 17.64,13.95 17.71,9.33Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Instagram</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#285fa8" d="M7.8,2H16.2C19.4,2 22,4.6 22,7.8V16.2A5.8,5.8 0 0,1 16.2,22H7.8C4.6,22 2,19.4 2,16.2V7.8A5.8,5.8 0 0,1 7.8,2M7.6,4A3.6,3.6 0 0,0 4,7.6V16.4C4,18.39 5.61,20 7.6,20H16.4A3.6,3.6 0 0,0 20,16.4V7.6C20,5.61 18.39,4 16.4,4H7.6M17.25,5.5A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 18.5,6.75A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 17.25,8A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 16,6.75A1.25,1.25 0 0,1 17.25,5.5M12,7A5,5 0 0,1 17,12A5,5 0 0,1 12,17A5,5 0 0,1 7,12A5,5 0 0,1 12,7M12,9A3,3 0 0,0 9,12A3,3 0 0,0 12,15A3,3 0 0,0 15,12A3,3 0 0,0 12,9Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="sr-only">Youtube</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#e42c27" d="M10,16.5V7.5L16,12M20,4.4C19.4,4.2 15.7,4 12,4C8.3,4 4.6,4.19 4,4.38C2.44,4.9 2,8.4 2,12C2,15.59 2.44,19.1 4,19.61C4.6,19.81 8.3,20 12,20C15.7,20 19.4,19.81 20,19.61C21.56,19.1 22,15.59 22,12C22,8.4 21.56,4.91 20,4.4Z" /></svg></span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="menu-buttons">
    <button id="main-menu-open"><span class="sr-only">Abrir menu</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M3,6H21V8H3V6M3,11H21V13H3V11M3,16H21V18H3V16Z" /></svg></span></button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div id="main-content">
  <div id="principal" class="search-form">
   <h2>Qual o seu problema?</h2>
   <form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Ex: Assinatura de E-mail">
     <button type="submit"><span class="sr-only">Pesquisar</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5C16,11.11 15.41,12.59 14.44,13.73L14.71,14H15.5L20.5,19L19,20.5L14,15.5V14.71L13.73,14.44C12.59,15.41 11.11,16 9.5,16A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 3,9.5A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 9.5,3M9.5,5C7,5 5,7 5,9.5C5,12 7,14 9.5,14C12,14 14,12 14,9.5C14,7 12,5 9.5,5Z" /></svg></span></button>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   <p><a href="#" id="scroll-newest-videos">Talvez a solução esteja aqui!</a></p>
  </div>
    </div>
<ul id="menu-links">
    <div class="menu-buttons">
     <button id="main-menu-close"><span class="sr-only">Fechar menu</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" /></svg></span></button>
    </div>
    <li class="search-bar">
     <form method="post" action="">
      <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="" placeholder="O que você procura?">
       <button type="submit"><span class="sr-only">Pesquisar</span><span><svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#000000" d="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5C16,11.11 15.41,12.59 14.44,13.73L14.71,14H15.5L20.5,19L19,20.5L14,15.5V14.71L13.73,14.44C12.59,15.41 11.11,16 9.5,16A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 3,9.5A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 9.5,3M9.5,5C7,5 5,7 5,9.5C5,12 7,14 9.5,14C12,14 14,12 14,9.5C14,7 12,5 9.5,5Z" /></svg></span></button>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.php">Página inicial</a></li>
    <li><a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="contato.php">Contato</a></li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar z-index negativo para resolver este problema. No seu caso ficaria:

HTML

```
   <input type="text" class="exemplo" name="" placeholder="Ex: Assinatura de E-mail">
```

CSS

```
   .exemplo{
   z-index:-99;
   }
```